# Trying To Save A Form Array Data Using CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, for-loop

This issue is started to do my head in! I am trying to build a basic invoice system for my site, which is using CakePHP.

However, I can save almost all of the data without any issues at all, its when I want to save two fields, 'workdes' and 'price' which are arrays, every time I try and save the data I get an error of Array to String!

Heres my code:

```
        $test = $this->request->data; 
        foreach($test as $test2 => $tets3) {

            $this->Invoicedata->create();

            $InvoiceGroupData = array(
              'Invoicedata' => array(
                'workdes' => $this->request->data['workdes'],
                'price' => $this->request->data['price']
              )
            );
            //debug($InvoiceGroupData); die();

            $this->Invoicedata->saveMany($InvoiceGroupData);
        }
```

This is what is inside $this->request->data:

```
'workdes' => array(
    (int) 0 => 'dfgdfg',
    (int) 1 => 'sswd'
),
'price' => array(
    (int) 0 => '500',
    (int) 1 => '100'
)
```

This is just test data, I can have anything from one input or five. So What I am doing wrong? I thought that the use of SaveMany was that is did save Arrays into the database.

The table / model name I am trying to save to is call Invoicedata, and the two tables within that are 'workdes' and 'price'.

Anything else I have not put into the question and is needed, please ask!

Please Help....

Many Thanks

Glenn.

UPDATE ::

These are the two sections of code I have tried, and I am still getting Array to String issue!!

CODE TRY 1:

```
        $WorkHolder = $this->request->data['workdes'];
        $PriceHolder = $this->request->data['price'];

        $MyData = array(
                      array('Invoicedata' => array('workdes' => $WorkHolder)),
                      array('Invoicedata' => array('price' => $PriceHolder)),
            );
        foreach($MyData as $test2 => $test3) {

            $this->Invoicedata->create();



            //debug($test3);

            $this->Invoicedata->saveMany($test3);
        }
```

CODE TRY 2:

```
            $WorkHolder = $this->request->data['workdes'];
            $PriceHolder = $this->request->data['price'];

            $MyData = array(
                      array('Invoicedata' => array('workdes' => $WorkHolder)),
                      array('Invoicedata' => array('price' => $PriceHolder)),
            );

            //debug($MyData); die();

            $this->Invoicedata->saveMany($MyData);
```

One with a foreach loop and one without, Code try 2 is what I tried 1st, now my code looks like code try 1. I have changed, or at lest i think I have changed my array data to that of want CakePHP needs it to be, so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reading the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-savemany-array-data-null-array-options-array).

From docs:

```
$data = array(
    array('Article' => array('title' => 'title 1')),
    array('Article' => array('title' => 'title 2')),
);
```

Your data should look like this.